# Why, suddenly, importing the exact same python module as before became so slow?

Tags: python

I am running a python script that calls local modules (with import), and since few days it became so slow.

I could not find the reason why it is so, neither on other Github posts or Google, that's why I am posting this.

Providing code won't be of much help, but here is the import that poses a problem:

```
import latplan
```

where *latplan* is [this](https://github.com/guicho271828/latplan) library

But again, this import did not pose any problem at all before...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`import` statements can be very slow in Python because they are allowed to execute arbitrary code as side effects; they don't just scoot for `class` and `def` keywords.

Now, as with any performance issue, it's hard to *guess* what exactly is taking so long without *profiling*. Luckily there's a builtin, specialised profiler for import time:

`python -X importtime -c "import latplant"`

I recommend using [tuna](https://pypi.org/project/tuna/) to visualise the reports.

Comment: Thnaks but as I mentioned, no change was made on the code that could result in this slow down, so the problem does not come from the types of imports of  things like this

Comment: Have you attempted to profile it ?